# Graphic library on Udoo

Tags: porting, graphic, microchip

I'm trying to use an OLED display attached to a UDOO embedded platform with Linux OS. The display would be connecting to the UDOO platform with SPI. Still I'm in the project architecture phase.

I believe I'd need to have a graphic library with the capability of drawing Fonts, simple polygons and bitmaps. I've read and found out that there are free graphic libraries available such as [stellarisware](http://www.ti.com/tool/sw-grl) and [microchip graphic library](http://www.microchip.com/stellent/idcplg?IdcService=SS_GET_PAGE&nodeId=2680&dDocName=en543091). But those libraries are intended for the particular platform only. Should I think of porting these graphic libraries in to UDOO?

Please advice me on how should I design my project by having an already available free graphics library.

Thank you for your valuable time.

Thilina

Comment: What's the point of tagging Microchip if you're not even talking about a PIC nor MPLAB ? You've got an Arduino Due ARM on this, try googling "Arduino graphic library", like this directly on the company page...
http://www.udoo.org/ProjectsAndTutorials/udoo-and-an-arduino-controlled-tft-lcd/

Comment: Thank you very much for the comment.
I added microchip just to know whether porting of microchip graphics library to any other platform has been carried out. Currently I'm learning Adafruit GFX Graphics Library. Thank you very much for the insight Jean